# SmartOS can't ping any ip that resolves to failover ip

Tags: networking, nat, solaris, failover, icmp

Our server is running SmartOS, we have 2 network cards one for internal use (10.x.x.x) and one external, i am able to ping any website / service except domains that resolve to our Failover IP (The IP just redirects to the pre-configured IP)

Essentially: (abcdefg.com -> 140.129.142.6 -> 94.130.125.129)

Whenever pinging abcdefg.com in this example, the ping command returns a lot of ICMP Host redirects, when tracerouting i can see that the packet ping pongs / bounces between the gateway and the server.

I can ping to external IP of the server without problem just when pining the Failover IP which should just point to the actual server ip the ping fails

As this is the first question i ever posted on serverfault / StackExchange sorry if i missed something.